# Нужна ли запятая перед «где» во фразе «стой где стоишь»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, фразеология

> Стой(,) где стоишь.

Это ведь некая устойчивая фраза, которая значит «не двигайся» / «стой неподвижно»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Практически во всех примерах из Нацкорпуса **запятая ставится** даже в том случае, если это команда, например:

*― **Стой, где стоишь**, я сказал! ― рявкнул Кустарь и, уже обращаясь к Игорю, продолжил: ― Я знаю, кто ты.* [Сергей Таранов. Мстители (1999)]

2. Таким образом, придаточное **не относится** к устойчивым выражениям и отделяется запятой.
3. Как это объяснить? Вероятно, **основное логическое ударение** в этой фразе всегда падает на первое слово "стой", и тогда после него делается фонетически обусловленная **пауза** в обязательном порядке. Эта пауза обозначается запятой.

При отсутствии паузы ударение падает на конец фразы, а глагол "стой" будет **в безударной позиции.**

Например: *Делай что хочЕшь.* Здесь ударением выделено только устойчивое выражение, но не сказуемое.

[Нацкорпус](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C)

Comment: А это? https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/380610/стой

Comment: Хочу сказать не об ударениях и даже не о нужности или ненужности запятой.  Вы пишете: "...делается фонетически обусловленная пауза в обязательном порядке".  По-моему, в таком предложении, реплике, приказе паузе вообще не место.

Comment: @oleedd  А это не ко мне, дорогой товарищ, а к Академику.  Прочитайте мой ответ. Я всего лишь ссылаюсь на Нацкорпус, а там разные есть примеры, например:  "Стой, где стоишь, не влезай в мой коридор своими грязными сапогами". Это не команда, здесь тоже запятую не надо ставить?
В команде  придаточное похоже на устойчивое сочетание, но и там все ставят запятую. Вот я и предлагаю возможную версию этого. И совсем не заслуживаю вашего «А это?», очень невежливого.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
 Интересное мнение.  Логически выделено слово «стой» (повышение тона). Но потом он должен где-то понижаться, это же не вопросительное предложение.  Я думаю, что после силового и тонического ударения на первом слове голос естественным образом понижается сразу. Впрочем, это я так думаю. А в общем-то этому предложению явно не хватает двух альтернативных ответов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Я говорю лишь о том, что независимо от повышения тона и его немедленного понижения пауза здесь не чувствуется. Насчёт запятой: если честно, меня устраивает и ее отсутствие (по интонационным или еще каким "устойчивым" причинам) и ее наличие (по грамматическим соображениям).

Comment: @oleedd Академикам кажется, что это устойчивое  выражение, вот и не поставили запятую. Но на практике получается,что оно таковым не является.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  К сожалению, мне все это не кажется.  Эту фразу можно воспринимать абстрактно, как в словаре. Но  на практике мы должны понимать и слышать, как она звучит в реальности. Вначале я  тоже думала, что запятая не нужна. Сейчас же, после просмотра всех текстов,  запись без запятой кажется мне неверной.  Ну а вопрос с паузой надо решать с помощью фонографа, не иначе.

Comment: Я бы тоже поставил запятую без оглядки! Здесь мною руководит чисто грамматика. Сплошь и рядом мы ставим запятые там, где нет паузы в речи.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  А что грамматика?  Давайте вспомним вопрос:  Это ведь некая устойчивая фраза, которая значит «не двигайся» / «стой неподвижно»?   В грамматике устойчивых сочетаний нет противоречия между интонационным и грамматическим принципами, там четкое соответствие.  А здесь вот такой интересный случай.

Comment: Там не академики, там разные словари. В данном случае словарь синонимов. На практике получается, что боятся самовольничать, потому что в правилах нет, а правила не развиваются, а этот словарь синонимов из новых — 2013 года (только у одного текста год выше). Здесь должно быть два варианта, смотря по контексту. Устойчивость тогда, когда нельзя добавить слово.

Comment: @oleedd В общем,  так. Я ведь словаря не видела, когда отвечала. И рассказала вам, как выглядит реальная письменная запись, как люди (писатели) пишут. И сама написала бы именно так, в любом  случае.  Мне не нравится фраза без знаков – она БЕЗДУШНАЯ, НЕЖИВАЯ.  Чего-нибудь еще добавить, чтобы участники форума меня поняли? А вы видели словарь, у вас другое мнение, почему вы не запишете его в поле ответа. Знаете ведь, что весь этот материал отправят в чат, а так бы информация сохранилась.

Comment: Не пишите больше – не отправят. :)